# Django-compressor js files not working when COMPRESS_ENABLED = True

Tags: django, django-compressor

When I leave `COMPRESS_ENABLED = False`, everything works fine but the js files I'm loading aren't compressed.

However, if I set `COMPRESS_ENABLED = True`, the compressed file appears to compress and load properly. The problem is, the libraries I'm compressing aren't loading properly. For instance, I'm getting `$ is not defined` errors for jQuery.

The only clue I can see is that I'm getting an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` error on line one of my compressed file. What do I need to do to allow this compressed file to be read by the browser?

Thanks!

My settings file is:

```
COMPRESS_ENABLED = True

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)
```

HTML is:

```
{% load compress %}

{% compress js %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/react/react.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/image-picker/image-picker.min.js"></script>
{% endcompress %}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ ... });` form instead?

Comment: `jQuery` is also undefined in the browser console.

Comment: Try introducing the files one by one to the `{% compress js %}` block. One of the files might not be safe for minification.

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony thanks - there are two files that seem to be holding it back - react.min.js and moment.min.js. Does that mean I should simply load these outside the Compressor block or is there something else to do?

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to minify files that have already been minified so maybe just include `moment.js` and `react.js` instead of the `.min.` versions. Alternatively as you mentioned, you can leave them outside the compress block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude minified js and css files from compressor and problem will be solved. (Solved by @Timmy O'Manhony comment)

```
{% load compress %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/react/react.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/image-picker/image-picker.min.js"></script>
{% compress js %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
{% endcompress %}
```